# How to disable WiFi interface with netplan?

Tags: networking, wireless, netplan

My `netplan` config at `/etc/netplan/wireless.yaml` seems to be working well for my WiFi-to-USB adapter, but I seem to still get the native interface to come up.  I would prefer to keep that down.  Right now, `sudo ifconfig wlp0s20f3 down` doesn't seem to be persisting across reboots with config:

```
# See also: https://netplan.io/reference
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlx7ca7b0babcf7:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.7.12/24] 
      gateway4: 192.168.7.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      access-points:
        "my_network":
          password: "my_password"
```

How can I adjust my netplan config to keep the native WiFi interface down?  Is that something that can only be configured to be persistently off elsewhere?

#### Additional info

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
```

Note I have a LAN I connect to:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 00
       serial: 0c:dd:24:1c:52:55
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-7629-generic firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 ip=10.53.189.39 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:d3510000-d3513fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:26:00.1
       logical name: ethA
       version: 12
       serial: 80:fa:5b:7a:b1:cc
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d3215000-d3215fff memory:d3210000-d3213fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: ethA.200
       serial: 80:fa:5b:7a:b1:cc
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=802.1Q VLAN Support driverversion=1.8 firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes port=MII
  *-network:1
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: wlx7ca7b0babcf7
       serial: 7c:a7:b0:ba:bc:f7
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl88x2bu multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
```

`/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` has contents:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

#### See also

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111258/32951

Comment: Your .yaml file is incorrect. You assign static IP, gateway, and nameservers, but you have dhcp4: true. It should be false. Is this a desktop or server installation? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: Editing.  So `wlx7ca7b0babcf7` is what I want up while the other native interface `wlp0s20f3 ` is what I want down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your `/etc/network/interfaces` to this:

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
#
auto wlp0s20f3
iface wlp0s20f3 inet manual
     pre-up ifconfig $IFACE down
     pre-down ifconfig $IFACE down
     down ifconfig $IFACE down
```

**Note**: you may have to `sudo apt install ifupdown`

---

Set your `/etc/netplan/wireless.yaml` to this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlx7ca7b0babcf7:
      addresses: [192.168.7.12/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.7.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      access-points:
        "my_network":
          password: "my_password"
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Comment: `/etc/netplan/wireless.yaml:17:7: Error in network definition: wlp0s20f3: No access points defined
      dhcp4: no`

Comment: @tarabyte I've updated my answer. See if it works now. Report back.

Comment: It unfortunately does not work to intentionally down it in `/etc/network/interfaces`, either with `down ifconfig $IFACE down`

Comment: @tarabyte Clarification. Is it coming UP at boot and connecting to some network, or just sitting there idle? Did you install ifupdown?

Comment: Adding a `pre-down ifconfig $IFACE down` and a `pre-up ifconfig $IFACE down` did it!  Isolating which one actually matters.

Comment: @tarabyte Great news! Let me know which one matters, and I'll update my answer to reflect that. Did you have to install ifupdown, or was it already installed?

Comment: @tarabyte fixed a small typo in my `/etc/network/interfaces` script... init->inet.

Comment: However it should not be necessary to do anything with ifupdown, because interfaces are down by default unless configured to be up. So where in your system is this other wifi interface being configured?  Is it being managed by Network Manager? Is there additional netplan yaml in a different file?

Comment: Both pre-up and pre-down are required.  With the pre-up and pre-down changes removed and `01-network-manager-all.yaml` removed, the additional `wlp0s20f3` native interface persists up.

Comment: @tarabyte Oh, you had more than one .yaml?!? Are there any more besides wireless.yaml? You never did answer my question about how wlp0s20f3 came up... was it connecting to a wireless network? So right now, after the edits in my answer, it's staying down, yes?

Comment: I never found how `wlp0s20f3` is getting upped.  After the edits, yes, this works.

Comment: @tarabyte In your NetworkManager `Wi-Fi Settings` panel, is there a wireless network configured there with `Connect Automatically` set?

Comment: `sudo nm-connection-editor` -> Gear Icon for WiFi network -> `General` tab -> Unchecked `Automatically connect to this network when it's available`.  The interface still shows up under ifconfig but not Tx/Rx bytes flow.  There seems to be no difference with and without this checked.  Feel free to DM me if you want me to gather more info.  Seems like too many hands in the cookie jar with all the apps that can control the network settings.

Comment: @tarabyte Since it's working now, I'm content to leave it be. Since we haven't found what's bring up the interface, the only other solution would be to reinstall Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this here in case somebody lands from Google.

I wasn't trying to disable Wifi specifically with Netplan, just disable it in any convenient way in a modern Ubuntu using Netplan.

Turns out the the best way that I found was to configure NetworkManager to ignore the wifi interface. I wasn't able to do it with Netplan only.

I found the information on how to do this [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/configuring-networkmanager-to-ignore-certain-devices_configuring-and-managing-networking).

Basically add a file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/99-unmanaged-devices.conf`

With the contents:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:ethWifi
```

(replacing ethWifi with the name of your wifi device.)

And then restart NetworkManager with the command:

```
systemctl reload NetworkManager
```

And Wifi interface was down and did not connect again.

Comment: This solution gives a really odd problem for me on Ubuntu 20.04. The secondary device is disabled however I seem to get two IP address' on the main interface.