# How can I keep my WiFi adapter in monitor mode?

Tags: networking

I have two WiFi interfaces (one internal WiFi card and one external USB adapter). I need one to be in monitor mode and the other to be in managed. Whenever I switch one of them to monitor mode, it switches back to managed in a few seconds. Here are the two ways I switched it to monitor mode:

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

and

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan mode monitor
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Since wlan0 kept switching back to managed, a quick google search said to run `sudo airmon-ng check kill` which fixed it, but it made my other WiFi interface unusable. Any other way I can keep wlan0 in monitor mode?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and my internal WiFi card is a RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter and my external USB WiFi adapter model is Alfa AWUS036NHA 802.11n

Comment: I suspect it is Network Manager that keeps changing the interface to managed. Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253449/how-to-disable-wifi-interface-with-netplan/1343933#1343933 Specify *wlan0*.

Comment: @chili555 That makes wlan0 unusable until removing that. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Unusable through Network Manager, I'm sure. However, will it go into and stay in monitor mode?