# I want to disable wifi USB on boot and enable it at any time

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp

I have configured this into `/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlx2887ba49932c` to disable the interface on boot:

```
auto wlx2887ba49932c
iface wlx2887ba49932c inet manual
    pre-up ifconfig $IFACE down
    pre-down ifconfig $IFACE down
    down ifconfig $IFACE down
```

because I saw it in [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253449/how-to-disable-wifi-interface-with-netplan).

However when I run `sudo ifup wlx2887ba49932c` because I want to enable the interface after boot, it says `ifup: interface wlx2887ba49932c already configured` and doesn't get up and get neither ip address. I want to get interface configuration via DHCP.

How can configure the `/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlx2887ba49932c` file to be able to enable the interface at any required time?

Comment: Is this a built in device or a dongle?

Comment: A dongle I guess. It is a wifi USB adapter.

Comment: Then way not just remove it and plug it in when you want it?

Comment: It is used in my laptop as a backup wifi interface. The laptop is a MSI laptop and its built-in wifi interface is not totally compatible with Ubuntu 22.04 because with some kernel versions and when connecting to some wifi network it fails. So I want to have this backup interface always available when needed. The wifi USB adapter is very small and it is easy to get lost, for this reason I want to have it always pluged in my laptop and only enable its interface when needed.

Comment: If I configure this line like this `iface wlx2887ba49932c inet dhcp` Ubuntu gets stuck in the boot.